# Why do fonts show up as boxes in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, fonts

I found that the font "MS Outlook" shows up as boxes on my computer. How do I display MS Outlook characters correctly? There are other fonts that show up as boxes in Windows 8, too.

[image: MS Outlook font is not recognized]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MS Outlook font only has a small number of actual characters (12, including a blank space) that are used as icons within the Outlook program. It is not designed to be used as an actual typeface:

[image]

The "boxes" are simply undefined characters within a font.

Answer (score 3):

"Showing boxes" is a sign that a given font does not support all the [glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) you want to render.

Guessing your locale is something like 'chinese' or 'japanese' or whatever. And the example-text of the font-preview app picked some text in your own language. Then it might be the case that it picked a text which needs glyphs which are not available in the font you want to use.

It might be better to use the charmap tool (`charmap.exe`). There you can see *all* the glyphs from a given font, not only a panagram.

Comment: Guessing from the character counts in the screenshot, it's simply *the quick brown fox…*

Comment: and knowing from my german font-preview it is a german phrase. which leads to the guess that msft now uses a local phrase instead of tqbf ...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2007/03/18/1909475.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. *Franz jagt…* (IIRC) has totally different character counts per word than what is shown in the screenshot. And I doubt some Japanese or Chinese sample sentence just happens to have identical character groups as *The quick brown fox*.

Answer (score 0):

This is special font which is used by Microsoft Outlook to render some interface elements.

Being special-purpose font, it does not contain regular characters, and you see the squares instead of test text.

The number of such fonts depends on the installed software.

Windows has a special font **Marlett** which is used to render Windows interface elements (in classic theme), such as window minimize, maximize, and close buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Some Outlook fonts don't support Unicode text format, so typecast the content to ASCII or UTF-8. It works for me.